# CSS3 background-size:cover not working in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, css, adfs

I've got a problem and it's driving me nuts. In short, I've tested the method in subj locally in plain HTML/CSS and it works perfectly:

```
<html style="
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px">

    <body style="padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;">
        <form style="width:100%;height:100%;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background.jpg',     sizingMethod='scale');
         -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');">
             <div style="float:right;width:500px;height:100%;background-color:#ffffff;padding:0px;border:0px;margin:0px;"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But trying to put it in ASP.Net fails utterly, as the image isn't resizing but shows up in intrinsic size.

```
<body>
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server" style="height:100%;width:100%">
        <div class="MainArea" runat="server">
            <div class="Header">
                <asp:Label ID="PageTitleLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <%
            string logoPath =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "logo" ];
            if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( logoPath ) )
                {
                %>
                <div class="GroupXLargeMargin">
                    <img src="<%= logoPath %>" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <%
                }
            %>
            <div class="GroupLargeMargin">
                <div class="TextSizeXLarge">
                    <asp:Label ID="STSLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="MainActionContainer">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0px;
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

body
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ff5500;
    color: #222222;
    background: url(../App_Themes/Default/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../App_Themes/Default/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../App_Themes/Default/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

I can see no reason for it not to work, but it doesn't. The ASP page is ADFS sign-in master page, if that matters. I've tried applying the background to various elements, and it's always the same - works in HTML, doesn't in ASP.Net.

Comment: This looks like user error.  This should work. Double check the HTML source being dumped out by ASP.NET, and check that your CSS is getting loaded correctly.  I did notice that you seem to be applying the background on the form element in the HTML, but the body in ASP.NET.  It helps if you start eliminating the differences.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of yours with the ASP.NET controls replaced with their HTML equivalents, and the background pointing to a (semi-random) image on the internets: http://jsfiddle.net/FRKea/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems I had to post it to make myself think better :)
It all comes down to a single statement in master page itself:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment that out and it all works.
Maybe that will be a shortcut for someone.